# Logical Constness: Function does not return string representation

Tags: c++, c++14

I have the following code, where I am expecting that the string representation will get returned. But it looks like I may be making some mistake as this code does not return the string representation.

```
/* Section 16.2.9.2 The C++ Programing Language
Bjarne Stroustrup 4th Edition Book, pages 462-463 */
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::to_string;

class Date {
private:
    int d, m,y;
    mutable bool cache_valid;
    mutable string cache;
    void compute_cache_value() const {
        string dd = to_string(d);
        string mm = to_string(m);
        string yy = to_string(y);
        cache = dd + "," + mm + "," + yy;
    }
public:
    explicit Date(int dd, int mm, int yy):d{dd}, m{mm}, y{yy} {};
    string string_rep() const;
};

string Date::string_rep() const {
    if (!cache_valid) {
        compute_cache_value();
        cache_valid = true;
    }
    return cache;
}

int main() {
    Date dx(25,3,2011);
    string s1 = dx.string_rep();
    cout << s1 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself: When I construct a `Date` what value does `cache_valid` have initially?

Comment: I would add initialization like `mutable bool cache_valid = false;`

Answer (score 2):

Initializing `cache_valid` to `false` makes the code work alright. Thank you all.